# How do I use an extended definition and not allow additional properties in a way that is compatible with multiple validators (JSON schema draft 7)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsonschema

I am creating a strict validator for a complex JSON file and want to re-use various definitions in order to keep the schema manageable and easier to update.

According to the [documentation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#extending) it is necessary to use `allOf` to extend a definition to add more properties. This is exactly what I've done, but I find that without use of `additionalProperties` set to `false` validation doesn't prevent arbitrary other properties being added.

The following massively cut-down schema demonstrates what I'm doing:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://example.com/schema/2021/02/example.json",
  "description": "This schema demonstrates how VSCode's JSON schema mechanism fails with allOf used to extend a definition",
  "definitions": {
    "valueProvider": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "example": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "alternative": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "required": [
            "example"
          ]
        },
        {
          "required": [
            "alternative"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "selector": {
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/valueProvider"
        },
        {
          "required": [
            "operator",
            "value"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "operator": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "IsNull",
                "Equals",
                "NotEquals",
                "Greater",
                "GreaterOrEquals",
                "Less",
                "LessOrEquals"
              ]
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "show": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "selector": {
          "description": "This property does not function correctly in VSCode",
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/selector"
            },
            {
              "additionalProperties": false
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

This works a treat in IntelliJ IDEA's JSON editor (2020.3.2 ultimate edition) when editing JSON against this schema (using a schema mapping). For example, the file `ex-fail.json`'s content of:

```
{
  "show": {
    "name": "a",
    "selector": {
      "example": "a",
      "operator": "IsNull",
      "value": "false",
      "d": "a"
    }
  }
}
```

Is correctly validated, simply highlighting "d" as not allowed, thus:

[image: Expected validation failure in IDEA]

However, when I use the very same schema and JSON file with VSCode (1.53.2) with vanilla configuration (except for a schema mapping) VSCode erroneously marks "example", "operator", "value" and "d" as not allowed. It looks like this in the VSCode editor:

[image: Unexpected validation failures in VSCode]

If I remove the `additionalProperties` definition from the `show.selector` property, both IDEA and VSCode indicate that all is well, including allowing the "d" property - in doing this I can simplify that property definition to:

```
        "selector": {
          "description": "This property does not function correctly in VSCode",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/selector"
        }
```

What can I do to the schema to support both IDEA and VSCode whilst disallowing additional properties where they should not appear?

PS: The schema mapping in VSCode is simply along the lines of:

```
{
    "json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "*/config/ex-*.json"
        ],
        "url": "file:///C:/my/path/to/example-schema.json"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Neither of these behaviours are correct! Yikes. Looks like I'll be filing bugs. Can you provide details of your exact setup / schema mapping in vscode so I can look into this further please? You can reach me on the JSON Schema slack server if required.

Comment: Thanks @Relequestual. Unfortunately I don't use slack. I have updated my schema to show the verbose definition (which actually has identical behaviour for both IDEA and VSCode compared with the original schema I posted).

Comment: No problem. I was reading the mapping documentation for VSCode just the other day, so I'll add this to my list of things to investigate.

Comment: @Relequestual I've edited again to add detail of the trivial schema mapping along with screenshots from IDEA and VSCode. This is in the `settings.json` file VSCode uses.

Comment: I've reached out to IntelliJ to see if I can get my hands on a copy for JSON Schema!

Comment: @Relequestual you should be able to use the community edition, with luck, though I can't remember if that supports JSON. Regardless it would likely be in their favour to donate a copy I would think...

Comment: @Relequestual one small question related to this: why does JSON schema not apply "additionalProperties" as false by default? This makes much more sense to me given that a schema is there in part to help a human edit the data. With additionalProperties as true by default a typo in a property name won't be detected and flagged.

Comment: Sure, let's address that. JSON Schema is a constraints based language. Anything that isn't limited or prohibited is allowed. This includes if additional properties are allowed, which often allows for extensibility.

Comment: @Relequestual it allows for extensibility but looses a lot because of not helping the author detect issues. Strict schemas are much more reliable, especially when there are specific mechanisms for extension (like you find with XML). This is the perspective I come from when developing schemata. It's less for the machine and more for the human. After all, you'll typically have the machine cherry pick out the details from the JSON document it requires. If the user added a property called "selectr" due to a typo, the machine will ignore it and the intended "selector" is missing.

Comment: @Relequestual can you link here any bugs you file? cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you ask with JSON Schema draft-07 or prior.

The reason is, when `$ref` is used in a schema object, all other properties MUST be ignored.

> An object schema with a "$ref" property MUST be interpreted as a
> "$ref" reference.  The value of the "$ref" property MUST be a URI
> Reference.  Resolved against the current URI base, it identifies the
> URI of a schema to use.  All other properties in a "$ref" object MUST
> be ignored.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-01#section-8.3

We changed this to not be the case for draft 2019-09.

It sounds like VSCode is merging the properties in applicators upwards to the nearest schema object (which is wrong), and IntelliJ IDEA is doing something similar but in a different way (which is also wrong).

The correct validation result for your schema and instance is VALID. See the live demo here: https://jsonschema.dev/s/C6ent

`additionalProperties` relies on the values of `properties` and `patternProperties` within the SAME schema object. It cannot "see through" applicators such as `$ref` and `allOf`.

For draft 2019-09, we added `unevaluatedProperties`, which CAN "see through" applicator keywords (although it's a little more complex than that).

---

Update:

After reviewing your update, sadly the same is still true.
One approach makes it sort of possible but involves some duplication, and only works when you control the schemas you are referencing.

You would need to redefine your selector property like this...

```
"selector": {
          "description": "This property did not function correctly in VSCode",
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/selector"
            },
            {
              "properties": {
                "operator": true,
                "value": true,
                "example": true,
                "alternative": true
              },
              "additionalProperties": false
            }
          ]
        }
```

The values of a property object are schema values, and booleans are valid schemas. You don't need (or want to) deal with their validation here, only say these are the allowed ones, followed by no `additionalProperties`.

You'll also need to remove the `additionalProperties: false` from your `definition` of `selector`, as that is preventing ALL properties (which I now guess is why you saw that issue in one of the editors).

It involves some duplication, but is the only way I'm aware of that you can do this for draft-07 or previous. As I said, not a problem for draft 2019-09 or above due to new kewords.

Comment: Thanks. I did try to "optimize" the structure a bit, which make contribute to your comment that I can't do this. I'll update the question's example schema so you can see the more verbose version that confirms with the documentation for draft 7...

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Sadly, the same still applies. It's a limitation of JSON Schema. I'll update my answer to propose a possible approach, but it does involve duplication.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer :D - I see the "duplication" you mention but it is at least somewhat shorter than actually repeating the full definitions of the properties. I'll give it a whirl and let you know.

Comment: Cool. This seems to work for both IDEA and VSCode! Not ideal, but quite manageable. Anything coming down the pipe with draft 8+ that will help me here?

Comment: We changed naming conventions, and "draft-08" is actually "draft 2019-09". We recently release "draft 2020-12". See http://json-schema.org/specification-links.html for details on that. 2020-12 is released, but website updates are pending.

Comment: Here if you want to talk about JSON Schema: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228905/room-for-relequestual-and-phil-w

Answer (score 1):

`additionalProperties` is problematic because it depends on the `properties` and `patternProperties`. The result is that `"additionalProperties": false` effectively blocks schema composition. @Relequestual showed one alternative approach, here is another approach that is a little less verbose, but still requires duplication of property names.

*draft-06 and up*

```json
{
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/base" }],
  "properties": {
    "bar": { "type": "number" }
  },
  "propertyNames": { "enum": ["foo", "bar"] },

  "definitions": {
    "base": {
      "properties": {
        "foo": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My understanding of `additionalProperties` has been much improved by the discussion I had with Relequestual. For me, the behaviour of JSON schema in the way it is essentially weakly constrained is a bad idea. What I really want to see is the ability to simply indicate that only explicitly defined properties are permitted anywhere in my JSON document, and where you can trivially augment any existing definition using an `"allOf" [{"$ref": "#/definitions/something"},{...}]"` approach. I will have to look into your alternative approach to make sure I understand it. Thanks.

Comment: Most of the time I see people trying to forbid undeclared properties it's an antipattern, but I agree that it's the right thing for your use case. That's why `unevaluatedProperties` was introduced. It's unfortunate that both of those editors are dragging their feet implementing this feature which as been around for a year and a half now and is so valueable for the use case they use JSON Schema for.

Comment: I am rather stuck with draft 7 right now given these are the two tools I need to use. In terms of anti-pattern usage I would be fascinated to understand where you're coming from. I still maintain that a directive at the schema level to make it strict match only would be better than having to "lock" each individual object, somewhat like you can with XML Schema.

Comment: One of these days I'll find time to write up my thoughts about the problems with `additionalProperties`.